# angularJs + firebase $createUser , new SDK error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I try to create user , with angular

```
myApp.controller('loginCtrl',['$scope','$firebaseAuth','config',function($scope,$firebaseAuth,config){

console.info('[APP-INFO] ~ loginCtrl Start')

var ref = new Firebase('https://myauth-tadmit.firebaseio.com/');
var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);

$scope.register =  function(){    
    auth.$createUser({
        email: $scope.user.email,
        password: $scope.user.password
    }).then(function(regUser){
        console.log('RegComplete User:' )
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log(error.message)
    });
}

}]);
```

and when i call register() function , i get i console error:

```
Projects created at console.firebase.google.com must use the new Firebase Authentication SDKs available from firebase.google.com/docs/auth/
```

I use angular 1.5.8 +

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.2.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are using a 2.x SDK to connect to a 3.x firebase. Check out the [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firebase sdk 3.

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('loginCtrl',['$scope','FbAuthService',function($scope,FbAuthService){

console.info('[APP-INFO] ~ loginCtrl Start')

$scope.register = function(email,password,info){

    FbAuthService.register(email,password,info);
}


}]);
```

then service:

```
    myApp.service('FbAuthService',['$firebaseAuth','$location',function($firebaseAuth,$location){

var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    storageBucket: "",
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);


// Authentication   
var authObj = $firebaseAuth();
var self = {};

self.register = function(email,password,info){
    authObj.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email,
        password
    ).then(function(newUser){

        //add Info from Signup to USERS => newUser.id => info(Object)
        var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('users').child(newUser.uid);
        ref.set({ firstname: info.firstname, lastname: info.lastname, uid: newUser.uid });
        $location.path('/login')
    }).catch(function(error){
       console.log(error.message)
    });
}

return self;
}]);
```

To get config value , just open your firebase app overview:
https://console.firebase.google.com/project/your-appName/overview

then click on "Add Firebase to your web app"

work fine!